# How to get started with Mac OS X development?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to know is there any tutorial for beginner？

Comment: I'd advise that you spend your effort towards learning how to write web applications, rather than a native application for a particular platform, as web applications will work on any device and are "always there".

Comment: Until you are without a network connection, then native apps are **always there**, instead of "always there". Also, this is the kind of answer I'd expect from a Google employee towards a Mac question. Please, answer the question if you want to contribute rather than be a knob about the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Buy [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&rls=en&q=cocoa%20programming%20for%20mac%20os%20x&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=8009817266096442357&sa=X&ei=mdybTcCZLpGH0QHT67DjAg&ved=0CDQQ8wIwAg#ps-sellers) and do every sample problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a lot of "getting started" material at the Apple's [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started).